# Entitlement com.apple.developer.playable-content is missing (CarPlay) with XCode15

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, carplay

Since XCode 15, we can't get our app in the app store no more. While uploading, we get the message: "Entitlement com.apple.developer.playable-content is missing".

The entitlement is for CarPlay and it worked for years -we did not change anything.Now with XCode 15, we had to remove CarPlay completely, otherwise we wouldn't get the app in the App Store no more.

Does anybody have an idea what do to?

Comment: UPDATE: Apple fixed it for us after a week...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I am running into this situation right now. It seems like the only entitlement that we still have is the `com.apple.developer.carplay-audio`. This is for the CarPlay framework instead of the Media Player framework.

I'm hoping this is an Xcode issue that gets resolved, otherwise I'm also looking at upgrading to the CarPlay framework.

I will update this if that works, or if I find another solution.